# Kernel of $\mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z}$ equals to $p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, formal-completions

Let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denotes the ring of $p$-adic integers, i.e., $\mathbb{Z}_p:= \varprojlim \mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z}$. Then consider the projection map $\pi_{n}: \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}/p^{n}\mathbb{Z}$. Then we know that $\pi_{n}$ is a ring map. I want to show that $\operatorname{ker} \pi_{n}=p^{n}\mathbb{Z}_p$.

It is clear that $p^{n}\mathbb{Z}_p \subset \operatorname{ker}\pi_{n}$. I am stuck at the converse. For $(x_r) \in \operatorname{ker}{\pi_n}$ we've $p^n \mid x_n$, and since $p^n \mid x_{n+1}-x_n$, $p^n \mid x_{n+1}$. Thus for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $i\geq n$ there exists integers $y_{i}$ such that $x_i=p^{n}y_i$, so that we obtain $(x_r)=p^{n}(y_r)$ But I'm unable to show that $(y_r) \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, i.e., $(y_r)$ is coherent. I need some help to complete it. Thanks.

Comment: Is not $y_r=x_{n+r}$? You can use that $x$ is coherent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would just write things out explicitly. We know that $x_n=0$. If we look at $x_{n+r} = \sum_{i=0}^{n+r-1}a_ip^i$, it restricts to $0$ mod $p^n$, hence
$$x_{n+r} = \sum_{i=n}^{n+r-1}a_ip^i = p^n \sum_{i=0}^{r-1}a_{i+n}p^i = p^ny_r,$$
where $y_r = \sum_{i=0}^{r-1}a_{i+n}p^i \in \mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z}$. As Phicar hinted, the coherence of $(y_r)$ now simply follows from the coherence of $(x_r)$. Explicitly, consider $x_{n+k} = \sum_{i=0}^{n+k-1}a_ip^i$ and $x_{n+j} = \sum_{i=0}^{n+j-1}b_ip^i$, where $k \geq j$. Then $x_{n+k} = x_{n+j}$ mod $p^{n+j}$, i.e. $p^n\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}a_{i+n}p^i = p^n\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}b_{i+n}p^i$. Therefore,
$$y_j = \sum_{i=0}^{j-1}b_{i+n}p^i = \sum_{i=0}^{j-1}a_{i+n}p^i \implies y_k \text{ mod } p^j = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a_{i+n}p^i \text{ mod } p^j = \sum_{i=0}^{j-1}a_{i+n}p^i = y_j.$$

Comment: What are the $a_i's$ ?

Comment: The $a_i$'s are integers in $\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$.

Comment: I understand $p$-adic integers in terms of inverse limit only. Can it be expressed as elements in the product space ?

Comment: With this point of view, a $p$-adic integer is a sequence $(x_r)$, where $x_r \in \mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z}$ for all $r$ and $x_k = x_j \mod p^j$ (with $k \geq j$). If you look at an element $x_k$ of your sequence $(x_r)$, it is an element of $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$, so we can write it uniquely in the form $x_k = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}a_ip^i$ for some $a_i \in \{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes I understand my last question. One more I'hv, in the second last line of your answer how  do you show  coherence of $(y_r)$ directly from $(x_r)$ ?

Comment: I have edited my answer so as to make the link between the coherence of $(x_r)$ and the coherence of $(y_r)$ more clear.